# How to determine what terrain / map type a marker or point is on?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Is it possible with leaflet.js or mapbox.js to determine what terrain / map type a marker is on.. For example the sea, land, road or buildings?

http://leafletjs.com/
http://mapbox.com/

Comment: Brief answer is no. You'd need to download osm data and query a database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your own map with [TileMill](http://tilemill.com), you could do this with interactivity: http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/tooltips/ You wouldn't necessary have to have a popup appear, but could instead use UTFGrid as a key/value store to indicate areas tapped on the map.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a method provided in the LeafletJS package (that I know of).

However, you can combine your Leaflet map with the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to return the `location_type`, which will tell you what type of terrain feature you're over.

It's not perfect but should give you the level of detail you're looking for.

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + marker._latlng.lat + ',' + marker._latlng.lng + '&sensor=false', function(data) {

  var terrain = data.results[0].geometry.location_type;

});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/NmJJ2/) showing how this could work.